# Мониторинг переводов между счетами python + dict + разные валюты

Tags: python, словари, dict

Есть 4 словаря-счета на бирже. С парами валюта - кво:

```
спот = {'dol': 10.0, 'eur': 22.0, 'lir': 34.0, 'cny': 45.0}
маржа = {'dol': 1.2, 'eur': 1.8, 'lir': 35.3, 'cny': 4.2}
крос = {'dol': 12.5, 'eur': 25.0, 'lir': 23.9, 'cny': 43.4}
фьюч = {'dol': 13.3, 'eur': 25.2, 'lir': 36.1, 'cny': 38.8}
```

Есть код который показывает из какого счета в какой был произведен перевод:

```
import copy

p_dict = {'spot': {'dol': 10.0, 'eur': 22.0, 'lir': 34.0, 'cny': 45.0},
          'marja': {'dol': 1.2, 'eur': 1.8, 'lir': 35.3, 'cny': 4.2},
          'cross': {'dol': 12.5, 'eur': 25.0, 'lir': 23.9, 'cny': 43.4},
          'future': {'dol': 13.3, 'eur': 25.2, 'lir': 36.1, 'cny': 38.8}}

n_dict = copy.deepcopy(p_dict)
n_dict['spot']['dol'] -= 1
n_dict['cross']['dol'] += 1

oper = None
for k1, v1 in n_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        v3 = p_dict[k1][k2]
        if v2 != v3:
            if oper is not None and abs(v2 - v3) == abs(oper[0]):
                print(f'Произошел перевод между счетами `{k1}` и `{oper[1]}`, валюта `{k2}` на {abs(oper[0])} ед.')
            else:
                oper = v3 - v2, k1
```

Нужно сделать так чтобы работало даже при разных валютах на счетах,  к примеру если в словаре `cross`  находиться `dol` а остальные валюты другие (проверил выдает KeyError).
Буду рад помощи

Comment: а предыдущий вопрос вы убили?

Comment: @splash58 предыдущий вопрос решен

Comment: те спрашиваете понемногу, глядишь, весь проект за вас и напишут. А вопросы/ответы можно потом и убивать. Интересная логика

Comment: если вы удаляете отвеченные вопросы, то я буду голосовать за закрытие ваших новых вопросов.

Comment: я ничего нигде не удалял

Comment: это просто второй акк, тк первый почему-то ограничили

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто добавить проверку на наличие ключа в словаре:

```
for k1, v1 in n_dict.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if k2 in p_dict[k1]:
            v3 = p_dict[k1][k2]
            if v2 != v3:
                if oper is not None and abs(v2 - v3) == abs(oper[0]):
                    print(f'Произошел перевод между счетами `{k1}` и `{oper[1]}`, валюта `{k2}` на {abs(oper[0])} ед.')
                else:
                    oper = v3 - v2, k1
```